# add roles in chef via code

Tags: chef-infra

I wish to do

```
knife role create <role-name> -y
```

via ruby code.I donot wish to write another knife plugin.I am able to print the entire role list(see below code). But then now how do i add a simple role with no recipe in the role?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'chef' 

Chef::Config[:node_name]='client_name'
Chef::Config[:client_key]='path to client cert.pem'
Chef::Config[:chef_server_url]="http://ur chef server:4000"    


puts Chef::Role.list
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The run list for a node is accessed via the `run_list` property.  First you have to load the node from the Chef server though.  The following code adds `role[foo]` to existing node `n`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'chef' 

Chef::Config[:node_name]='client_name'
Chef::Config[:client_key]='path to client cert.pem'
Chef::Config[:chef_server_url]="http://ur chef server:4000"    

node = Chef::Node.load('n')
node.run_list << "role[foo]"
node.save
```

For help figuring out how the Chef Ruby interface works I usually do "gem contents chef | xargs grep whatever" and have a good look around.

Comment: node.run_list << "recipe[foo]"
adds a recipe i wish to add a role
IF i create a role via command
    {knife role create <role-name> -y} 
and then do node.run_list << "<role-name>" it still adds as a recipe

Comment: I was able to make it work with code node.run_list << "role[<role-name>]"

Comment: I've edited the answer to use roles instead of recipes which actually answers the question.